# Regular expression with multiple endings

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
idx  name
1    "NM_014855.2(AP5Z1):c.80_83delGGATinsTGCTGTAAACTGTAACTGTAAA (p.Arg27_Ala362delinsLeuLeuTer)"
2    "NM_014630.2(ZNF592):c.3136G>A (p.Gly1046Arg)"
3    "NM_000410.3(HFE):c.892+48G>A"
4    "NC_000014.9:g.(31394019_31414809)_(31654321_31655889)del"
```

I need to extract whatever follows the `':'` character, until any of the following:

- `" ("`
- `"del"`
- `{end of string}`

I have tried the following:

```
df.str.extract(r"\):(.*) \(|\n")
```

But it doesn't work for all the cases.

How can I properly specify the condition I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lazy match `*?` to minimize how much the `.*` will capture, then specify the stop conditions you're looking for:

```
df.str.extract(r":(.*?)(?:\(|del|$)")
```

Regular expressions normally match the longest possible string, but `?` switches it to match the *shortest* possible string.

Comment: *Regular expressions normally match the longest possible string* is a wrong statement. Greedy quantifiers make patterns match up to the right-most occurrence of the subsequent subpattern, and lazy quantifiers make patterns match up to the leftmost occurrences (first found).